# npm install webpack config.js

Tags: reactjs, npm

Here is my package.json file and im trying to run command - 'npm run webpack'.

```
{
    "name": "react-graphql2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
        "dev-https": "webpack-dev-server --https",
        "prettier": "prettier --write './{src,tests}/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,json,css,scss}'",
        "start": "yarn run build",
        "test": "jest --coverage",
        "testDev": "jest"
```

When I run this command I get the below output and the package is built without issues-

```
laks2@1976190:~/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2$ npm run build

> react-graphql2@1.0.0 build /Users/laks/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2
> webpack

webpack.config.js
clean-webpack-plugin: /Users/laks/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2/dist/js/*.js has been removed.
```

Now, I move the same project to a different folder and run the same command, now I dont see the webpack.config.js being passed -

```
laks2@1976190:~/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2$ npm run build

> react-graphql2@1.0.0 build /Users/laks/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2
> webpack


clean-webpack-plugin: /Users/laks/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2/dist/js/*.js has been removed.
```

Comment: You project was always under `~/projects/spa-test/react-graphql2`. I did not see `you move the same project to a different folder`.

Comment: It was moved, i just pasted the old thing and changed the error msg

Comment: You moved the entire folder including node_modules? 
You did not do `npm run install` in the new folder? 
And have you tried to do `npm ls>old.txt` and `npm ls>new.txt` to compare the versions of packages in the 2 folders? Otherwise, try to delete `node_modules`, `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install` in the 2 folders to compare the outputs.

Comment: I tried on the new directory and get this error- npm ls > ~/Downloads/new.txt..
npm ERR! peer dep missing: jquery@1.9.1 - 3, required by bootstrap@4.4.1

Comment: Sometimes this error doesn't hurt anything. And I also do not think this is the reason of your question. You still can compare the txt files to see the differences from the 2 folders.